# SVG circle animation on hover doesn't work

Tags: animation, svg, geometry, hover

Atm im trying to recreate the SVG circle animation when you hover over the navigation menu buttons as shown on this site: https://5scontent.com/. On my site the circle appears when refreshing and disappears afterwards.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Alata';
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navbar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;


}
.svg-container{
  position: absolute;


}
.svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 1125px;

}
.symbol {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  transition: all 3s linear;
  

}
nav ul li a:hover + .svg-container .symbol{
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;

}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 2px;

}
```

```html
<body>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <div class="svg-container">
            <svg width="100" height="100" class="svg">
              <circle cx="50" cy="10" r="4" stroke-width="4" class="symbol"/>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

This is my first question on here, so bare with me if i have put it together in a more confusing way. :)

Comment: You're crossing the shadow-dom boundary with your CSS selector. That's not valid.

Comment: Since im only 4 weeks into developing, i dont really understand your answer. Could you elaborate it to a newbie like me. (sry)

Comment: nav ul li a:hover + .svg-container .symbol is partly referencing the symbol and partly the symbol's parents, you can't do that and have it work.

Comment: So i should reference it only to the symbol?

Comment: There may be other issues, there seems a lot of things there, perhaps you could cut it down further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see: you have a `div` element as a child of a list `ul`. This is not valid HTML.

I would put the svg inside the `a` element next to the text and do

```
a:hover > svg .symbol{
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

Also the value for the `stroke-dasharray` and for the `stroke-dashoffset` is too big. In your case the value to be used is: `25.13`. In order to know what value to use you can calculate the perimeter of the circle as 2 * Math.PI * 4 where 4 is the radius of the circle.

Yet another error is the size of the svg element: `width="100" height:"100"` when the circle has a radius `r="4"` I would use a 20x20 svg element.

For clarity I've simplified your code:

```css
ul li{display:inline-block; text-align:center;padding:0 1em;}
a{color:white;}
body{background:black;color:white}


.symbol {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 25.13;
  stroke-dashoffset: 25.13;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

a:hover > svg .symbol{
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
<a href="#"><span>aaaaaaa</span><br>
<svg width="20" height="20"  class="svg">
     <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="4" stroke-width="1" class="symbol" stroke="gold" fill="none"/>
  </svg></a>
  </li>
  <li>
<a href="#"><span>bbbbbbb</span><br>
<svg width="20" height="20"  class="svg">
     <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="4" stroke-width="1" class="symbol" fill="none"/>
  </svg></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do not understand why such a good answer in my opinion with detailed explanations was left without votes in favor. Supporting good answers always inspires to write new answers